# How is the baffle board of this stove able to heat up without combusting?

Tags: garage, fireplace, stove, chimney, firewood

I'm not sure if this question is right for this site, but since it is home improvement-related I thought I'd ask.

I recently helped my family acquire [this stove](https://www.usstove.com/rural-king/us1269e/) from a local distributor, and whilst putting it together, I noticed a big flat board covering almost the entire top of the stove where the two cooking burners are. The material in it feels like styrofoam, which feels like it might instantly burst into flames if exposed to the heat of the fire. From what I read, this is called a *baffle board* or *baffle plate*, which is supposed to aid in secondary combustion to ensure that as much heat is generated and not being lost through the flue pipe.

Additionally, I noticed that the flue collar has a hole where I assume the licenced NFI professional would put in a damper or another baffle plate that you would twist by hand. I'm not sure what the purpose of this would be, except that I also read that older fireplaces have dampers, which need to be open to ensure that no smoke backs up into the room.

Can anyone help clarify this? If y'all need any pictures, I'd be happy to include them. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps ceramic or asbestos?

Comment: It doesn't feel like ceramic because it is soft and spongy, like styrofoam. Asbestos? I thought that's been banned for a while now because of its toxicity, and this is a relatively new stove.

Comment: Could you be looking at the packaging material that covers a metal baffle plate ? Maybe a pic of the actual plate.

Comment: Yes, please provide an actual pic of the item in question on your actual stove. A wider shot to show us where in the stove it is, and a close up shot so we can see details of what you're seeing.

Comment: Please stick to "one question per question" and link them if they are related. *i.e.* [edit] this question, cut the material that starts with "additionally", make a **new** question, paste, and include a link in each to the other, related, question. As well as providing pictures...

Answer (score 3):

Ceramic (and "non-ceramic" or silica-free - less hazardous to handle) wool is a common refractory material that's flexible/soft. The product sequece generically would be from Asbestos (whoops - not safe) to ceramic (whoops, not safe) to the current era of "non-ceramic" products - though I don't know that the ceramic versions have actually been banned.

[image: "Superwool" ceramic fiber insulation image from Lynn Manufacturing]

Vermiculite board is a grayish product sold for stove use. You should see a coarse grain in the material, and perhaps reflections from the mica on close examination (vermiculite is steam-expanded mica)

[image: Image of vermiculite board from efireplace store]

[Perlite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlite) is a "more styrofoam-like" (or whiter, anyway) volcanic material,  but it crushes more than being "spongy." it's typically available as loose-fill or as boards. You should see a coarse grain in the material.

[image: Perlite board image from MG-Materials.com]

Rigid ceramic-fiber boards are also common. And indeed. while poking around, I find "universal ceramic fiber baffle board, 2300°F rated" as a product. It's probably ceramic fiber board, lacking a picture.

[image: kaowoll boards image from foundryservice.com]

**Modern** stoves use refactory/insulating baffles to attain higher temperatures (compared to uninsulated steel or cast-iron baffles) that help burn more of the wood products, creating less creosote and delivering more efficiency and a cleaner burn.

Answer (score 2):

As Solar Mike says, the baffle plate is normally metal and the purpose is to reflect the heat back in the chamber.

> WHAT DOES A BAFFLE PLATE DO?
> The simplest way to describe a baffle plate, which is placed at the top of the fire chamber, is a deflector shield which reflects heat back into the combustion chamber. This ensures that as much heat as possible is retained in the stove and emitted into the room in a controlled manner. If there was no baffle plate, which is simply a curved part made of cast iron, heavy steel, stainless steel or vermiculite, then heat would be lost through the flue system and not circulated around the room.

[Stove Baffle Plate](https://www.bowlandstoves.co.uk/blog/stove-advice-and-maintenance/stove-baffle-plate-might-need-replaced/)

It is probably **vermiculite**

> Vermiculite is a hydrous phyllosilicate mineral which undergoes significant expansion when heated

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermiculite)

The damper allows you to control the rate of combustion.  Once the fire is lit, you can turn it to reduce the rate of combustion and hence the heat output from the beast.  We used to top up the stove with firewood (different model, different country) before going to bed and then turn the damper fully.  It would keep producing heat all night.

> A damper is a valve or plate that stops or regulates the flow of air inside a duct, chimney, VAV box, air handler, or other air-handling equipment. A damper may be used to cut off central air conditioning (heating or cooling) to an unused room, or to regulate it for room-by-room temperature and climate control

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damper_(flow))

Comment: That makes sense, but how were you able to sleep if the damper was completely blocking the opening to the chimney? Wouldn't you have been breathing in all that smoke? That's what happened when we first tried it. Or do you wait until everything has burned and it's only glowing embers?

Comment: It's a loose mechanical fit, so there are tiny gaps between the damper and the flue.  Being different materials I would expect them to expand and contract at different rates.  So, I would expect it to be a loose fit.